# Product of two conditional probabilities

Tags: probability

Is $P(X_1,\dots,X_N \mid C)*P(C)$ equal to $P(X_1 \mid C) * P(X_2,\dots,X_N\mid C) * P(C)$?

I can't find the proof by myself.

**EDIT**

I found the associated article on wikipedia ([Conditional Independence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence)).

Comment: not in general. If and only if the events are conditionally independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No -- only if $X_1$ is conditionally independent of $X_2,\ldots,X_N$ given $C$.